# Why is the memory limit getting exceeded?

Tags: c++, memory-limit

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    string a, b;
    int buffer;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (a[i] < 92)
        {
            a[i] += 32;
        }
        if (b[i] < 92)
        {
            b[i] += 32;
        }
    }
    if (a < b) 
    {
        cout << -1;
    } 
    else if (a > b)
    {
        cout << 1;
    } 
    else if (a == b) 
    {
        cout << 0;
    }
    cin>>buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

Memory limit is being exceeded , the memory used is :262100 KB

Desired Output: If the first string is less than the second one, print "-1". If the second string is less than the first one, print "1". If the strings are equal, print "0". Note that the letters' case is not taken into consideration when the strings are compared.

Comment: How long will the input be at maximum? Is it guaranteed that the second string is always longer or has equal length than the first one?

Comment: It probably wont change anything, but you forgot to `#include <string>`

Comment: Also what is the memory limit?

Comment: Just guessing from the magic numbers, but it seems like `std::tolower` would be more appropriate choice.

Comment: As a side note: depending on your OS and compiler, you probably have `strcasecmp`, so `cout << strcasecmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str());` would be all you need: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp

Comment: That last test (`else if (a == b)` isn't needed; the code has already examined `a < b` and `a > b`; if both of those fail, then `a` and `b` must be equal.

Answer (score 3):

When `b` has less characters than `a` then you are going out of bounds here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) 
{
    if (a[i] < 92)
    {
        a[i] += 32;
    }
    if (b[i] < 92)   // <<----- here !
    {
        b[i] += 32;  
    }
}
```

`b[i] += 32` is undefined behavior when `i >= b.size()`. You should transform the two strings seperately. I see no way to make your code use less memory, so that shouldn't be the problem. Though in the presence of undefined behavior anything can happen.

Comment: Transforming both at once is a (possibly misguided) optimization. If `b` is longer than `a`, the tail of `b` doesn't have to be adjusted; if all the characters up to the length of `a` are equal, then `b` comes after `a`. The problem is in the loop limit:it should be `std::min(a.length(), b.length())`, for the reason that this answer describes. +1.

Comment: @PeteBecker very good point, though lets keep it simple. First understand why it is wrong, then OP can still improve it